# Variable assignment from JSON not setting all the values at the same time (React) and returning undefined for one variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, undefined

I'm making an async call to an API and then setting the data I get back to my state variable all inside a useEffect function. Out side of that function I then destructure the values into variables and the render them to the screen.

The issue is that the instructions variable is still undefined at time of render and I'm a bit confused why when the others render fine.

(The instructions variable is also an array of objects)

**Top Component**

```
const RecipePage = () => {

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const params = useParams();
const recipeSlug = params.recipeSlug;
const recipeID = params.id;

useEffect(() => {

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://tasty.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/detail',
        params: { id: recipeID },
        headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'tasty.p.rapidapi.com',
            'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY
        }
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const recipeInstructions = await axios.request(options);
        setData(recipeInstructions.data);
        console.log(recipeInstructions.data);
        console.log(data);
    }
    fetchData().catch(console.error);

}, [recipeID]);

const { name, country, slug, instructions, beauty_url } = data;

console.log(data.instructions);
console.log(name);

return (
    
    <>
        <header className="topBar">
            <Link to={`/`} className='normal'>
                <div className='title'>
                    <SectionTitle titleText="Test Test" />
                    <SectionTitle titleText="Cooking Club" />
                </div>
            </Link>
        </header>
        <div>
            <SectionTitle titleText={name} />
            <div className="image">
                <img src={beauty_url} alt="recipe" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <section>
            <p>Serves {data.num_servings} </p>
            <p>Prep Time {data.num_servings} </p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        </section>
        <div>{country}</div>
        <div>{slug}</div>
        <div>slug: {recipeSlug}</div>
        <RecipeInstructions instructions={instructions} />         
    </>
)
```

}

**Instructions Component**

```
const RecipeInstructions = ({instructions}) => {
console.log(instructions);
const instructionList = instructions.map((instruction, i) =>{
    return <li key={instruction.id} id ={instruction.id}>{instruction.display_text}</li>
});

return(
    <ul className="instructionList">
       {instructionList}   
    </ul>
)
```

}

export default RecipeInstructions;

**JSON Shape**

```
{
"country": "US",
"name": "Tomato And Ginger Pressure Cooker Short Ribs",
"id": 8115,  
"original_video_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/video-api-prod/assets/394e5b5d88d44a8abff0bf146ccda0b8/Campbells_TomatoGingerRibs_BFV88856_SQHero.mp4",
"cook_time_minutes": null,
"description": "",
"slug": "tomato-and-ginger-pressure-cooker-short-ribs",
"instructions": [
    {
        "appliance": null,
        "id": 70698,
        "display_text": "Season the short ribs all over with salt and pepper.",
        "position": 1,
        "start_time": 4166,
        "end_time": 14133,
        "temperature": null
    },
    {
        "display_text": "Turn the pressure cooker on to the Sauté setting. Add the olive oil to the pot and heat until shimmering. Working in batches, add the short ribs and sear on all sides until browned, 2–3 minutes per side. Once all of the short ribs have been seared, return to the pot, nestling to fit in an even layer.",
        "position": 2,
        "start_time": 0,
        "end_time": 0,
        "temperature": null,
        "appliance": null,
        "id": 70699
    },
    {
        "start_time": 16500,
        "end_time": 30333,
        "temperature": null,
        "appliance": null,
        "id": 70700,
        "display_text": "In a small bowl, whisk together the soy sauce, beef broth, sesame oil, red pepper flakes, brown sugar, garlic, and ginger.",
        "position": 3
    },
    {
        "end_time": 61500,
        "temperature": null,
        "appliance": null,
        "id": 70701,
        "display_text": "Pour the sauce and Campbell’s® Tomato Soup into the pot over the short ribs. Secure the lid and turn off the Sauté setting, then set to pressure cook on high for 1 hour.",
        "position": 4,
        "start_time": 50500
    },
    {
        "end_time": 0,
        "temperature": null,
        "appliance": null,
        "id": 70702,
        "display_text": "In a small bowl, whisk together the cornstarch, water, and mirin until smooth.",
        "position": 5,
        "start_time": 0
    },
    {
        "end_time": 47000,
        "temperature": null,
        "appliance": null,
        "id": 70703,
        "display_text": "Release the pressure valve until all the steam has been released. Transfer the short ribs to a bowl and skim off any fat from the surface of the braising liquid. Turn on the Sauté setting and stir the cornstarch slurry into the braising liquid. Bring to a simmer and cook until the sauce has thickened, about 3 minutes. Return the short ribs to the pressure cooker and turn to coat in the sauce.",
        "position": 6,
        "start_time": 35000
    },
    {
        "position": 7,
        "start_time": 93000,
        "end_time": 98333,
        "temperature": null,
        "appliance": null,
        "id": 70704,
        "display_text": "Serve the short ribs over white rice and garnish with sliced scallions and sesame seeds."
    },
    {
        "position": 8,
        "start_time": 100000,
        "end_time": 103000,
        "temperature": null,
        "appliance": null,
        "id": 70705,
        "display_text": "Enjoy!"
    }
], 
"beauty_url": "https://img.buzzfeed.com/video-api-prod/assets/dc16dd0e35f2480ba1d68badac0eec99/InstantPotShortRibs_Pinterest.jpg",
"num_servings": 4,
"facebook_posts": []
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useEffect hook is first executed after the first initial render, also the request is asynchronous meaning there will be at least one render before receiving the network response and the data object being populated with the value for instructions.

This is expected behaviour, you can choose to defer rendering part of the component until the data is fetch, or provide some loading state.

Comment: I did have a feeling it was  something to do with the async function but in that case how come all the variables don't return undefined? When I take out the ReceipeInstructions component at the bottom it works fine and the other tags are rendered with the correct info

Comment: I don't know what is meant by 'all the variables' but I guess it works when you remove RecipeInstructions because then it is not throwing an undefined error on the map function.

Comment: I mean the name, country, slug & beauty_url variables. I'm not getting any undefined errors with those when it comes to rendering. When I try to just access a single value from instructions (instructions[0].display_text) and display that in a div it gives me errors. I added {instructions && <RecipeInstructions instructions={instructions} />} and it works so thanks for your help!

Comment: I see what you mean now, the problem is attempting to access properties of an undefined value.  For example instructions[0].display_text will throw an error when instructions is undefined, but if you expect it to undefined at some point you could use the optional chaining operation (AKA ?).  For example, `instructions?.[0]?.display_text` would not throw an error, instead the value returned would be undefined.

Comment: Is that only an issue with arrays? (I know I'm asking a lot of questions lol). One of the things I'm rendering is <p>Serves {data.num_servings} </p>. I didn't destructure num_servings and accessed it directly from the data object and that was fine too

Comment: The problem is not specific to Arrays, it applies to any undefined object (incl. Arrays) when you attempt to access one of it's properties, functions etc.  The optional chaining operator will work in all instances e.g. `instruction?.display_text` ; although it's not always the best option.  

Your example of `data.num_servings` is working because `data` is not undefined. It's perfectly fine to access the property with the dot notation, you do not need to destruct them, just as long as the object is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're already redirected to the dedicated page so you have or not the recipeId no need to use array of dependencies in the useEffect
You can use a conditionnal render since your call is asynchrone , you can display a gif loading for exemple once done you can display the informations.

```js
const RecipePage = () => {

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const params = useParams();
const recipeSlug = params.recipeSlug;
const recipeID = params.id;

useEffect(() => {
   setIsLoading(true)
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://tasty.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/detail',
        params: { id: recipeID },
        headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'tasty.p.rapidapi.com',
            'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_KEY
        }
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const recipeInstructions = await axios.request(options);
        setData(recipeInstructions.data);
        console.log(recipeInstructions.data);
        console.log(data);
    }
    fetchData().catch(console.error);
    setIsLoading(false)
}, []);

const { name, country, slug, instructions, beauty_url } = data;

console.log(data.instructions);
console.log(name);
if(isLoading) {
return (
<div> here dispolay a gif loading </div>
)};
return (
    
    <>
        <header className="topBar">
            <Link to={`/`} className='normal'>
                <div className='title'>
                    <SectionTitle titleText="Test Test" />
                    <SectionTitle titleText="Cooking Club" />
                </div>
            </Link>
        </header>
        <div>
            <SectionTitle titleText={name} />
            <div className="image">
                <img src={beauty_url} alt="recipe" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <section>
            <p>Serves {data.num_servings} </p>
            <p>Prep Time {data.num_servings} </p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        </section>
        <div>{country}</div>
        <div>{slug}</div>
        <div>slug: {recipeSlug}</div>
        <RecipeInstructions instructions={instructions} />         
    </>
)
```

Comment: Your answer is not correct according to React best practices and will only work depending on the Router being used.  For example, it should work with React Router but will not work with Nextjs Router as params are side effects and not available on the first render.

Comment: There is no indication that he use next here !!!!

Comment: No I didn't say there was, but to provide an answer that works consistently you should consider this.  This answer is flawed and against React's best practices of  using exhaustive dependency arrays.

Comment: there is no "exhaustive dependency arrays" i used empty array dependeny that mean componentDidMount in react old versions. he send id params from other page this props is send one time so there is no need to use array of dependeny
There is no bad practice in my answer , please give a good arguments ^^

Comment: Did I ask what an empty array meant? NO  

The value is not being sent from another page, it's coming from the hook useParams which takes it from the router.  Depending on how this is implemented today, or changes in the future, it's not guaranteed.

Yes there should be an exhaustive list of array dependencies, this is how you can be sure the effect is run at the correct times.  These are React's recommendations.

Comment: This still didn't work for me but I'll have a look into conditional rendering, thanks!